# Dymo Labelwriter SDK Not Printing Correctly

Tags: vb.net, printing, dymo

I have created an application in VB.Net using Dymo's SDK for printing labels. Some of the users are using the 450 model, and some are using the 450 Twin Turbo. I have set it up to print the contents of a textbox, including a procedure to determine if the user is using the Twin Turbo or not, and which label size to print to if so. 
Anyways, this all seems to work fine on my system, but the problem I'm facing is that the actual users of the application also occasionally use Dymo Label v.8, and when they go to use my application, it will print whatever the last label was that they created in Label v.8, rather than the label in the application that I made.
I could be wrong, but my assumption is that the old label is hanging up in some kind of memory queue somehow, and I just need to clear it from memory. (I know, I'm not using the proper terminology... I speak gooder English, I promise. In case it's not obvious at this point, I've never heard of Dymo Labelwriter or the SDK until this project)

Here's my printing Sub:

```
DymoAddIn.StartPrintJob()
If  GlobalVariables.label = "Left" Then 'Determine if printing on small spool
    DymoLabels.SetField("Address", TextBox.Text) 'Applies content of textbox to label
    DymoAddIn.Print2(1, False, 0) 'Prints on the left spool
Else
    DymoLabels.SetField("Address", TextBox.Text)
    DymoAddIn.Print2(1, False, 1) 'Prints on the right spool
End If
DymoAddIn.EndPrintJob()
```

I assumed that EndPrintJob() would clear everything, but maybe I'm completely misunderstanding.
How can I stop the label writer from printing an old label that has nothing to do with my program? Why is it acknowledging the labels I make on my system and printing those, but not the ones that the actual clients use?

Ideas?
And if I'm missing key information that would help, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. Instead of "0" or "1", it's actually "Left", "Right", or "Auto". After that, it just required a bit of fiddling, and I got it done.